# Running the Laravel on another IP

Tags: php, rest, ubuntu, frameworks, laravel-5

I use ubuntu and need to running the Laravel another IP?

For example another IP: 192.168.25.9. Can someone help me?

```
192.169.25.9:8080/api/users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem like so:

```
php -S 192.168.25.9:8080 server.php
```

This way, I can access my local machine to another machine.